# How to write multiline HQL code?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

How can multiline `HQL` sql queries be written in java so that they remain readable?

```
private static final String QUERY = 
   "SELECT p.FirstName, pp.PhoneNumber" + 
   "FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person AS p" + 
   "JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.PersonPhone AS pp" + 
        "ON p.BusinessEntityID = pp.BusinessEntityID" + 
   "ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
```

Are there better solutions to this?

Comment: Put the sql into a file and read file into String.

Comment: If I have several queries, I prefer to store mine in an XML Properties file, and read them in with a Properties object. When you wrap the value contents with a CDATA block, formatting is exactly preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: **it depends** on what degree of readability you want to achieve.

There's probably no way to write readable queries among lines of code and in the same time having certain code style (so that reformat option in IDE wouldn't spoil your efforts) and being able to modify it easily.

So you have to figure out some bypass. You can put the query into text files, xml files or use some IDE tool - which is my choice. If I cannot understand/modify my query which is split into many lines I just use my favourite `IntelliJ IDEA`'s tool:

[image: creating, reading, editing queries in IntelliJ IDEA]
(This is my `JPA` battlefield, so don't look at the query :) )